# How to switch to Hiragana keyboard

Tags: keyboard, language

I am new to linux and I have just installed elementary OS 5.1.7 hera (built on Ubintu 18.04.4 LTS).
I can't change the keyboard to hiragana layout. When I go to system settings>keyboard>layout and add japanese(kana), I can only type in katakana.
How can I fix this? Please be aware I am new to linux and will need a lot of hand holding.
Thanks,
Pablo

Answer (score 0):

You've to add Input method also, And make sure **ibus daemon** is running on start, then you can alwasy change layout by **alt+shitf** and change input method by **ctl+space**(Won't work if ibus daemon not running)

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, it seems that the keyboard layout is not the roman input method for hiragana. How can we achieve this kind of layout?

Comment: Okay - thanks Raj - I finally have made it work. Thank you so much for you assistance. All the best.